Vmware Kali Linux machine issue with SMBus
When I start my Virtual Kali Linux machine in VMware, I get the following error message: piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!, then the logo of Kali, the prompt to log in (disappears in a fraction of a second) and finally a dark screen with a blinking cursor _, that I can't interact with when typing.
Here, I found a similar issue with a Ubuntu machine, but all I could do was add this line cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101" into the vmx file, since I could not enter into recovery mode, having the blinking cursor again!!
This is what I get:

I would like to know what is this issue and how we can solve it.

Looks suspiciously like the graphics side isn't working correctly. Does it boot to text mode?

No, it showed the Kali logo!

All I see in the picture is black. Perhaps describing in the question what you see would help?

@ChrisDavies that's all what I get. I described it: the error message, and then the black screen with the blinkig cursor, that's it!

You just said you got the Kali logo? I'm confused - where does that fit in the sequence of "the error message, and then the black screen with the blinking cursor, that's it"?

I am sorry you are confused there were 2 sequences the first is described in my post and the second is when I restart the vm (no logo), if you have any confusion contact me I will send you the a full video if you like

Oh I see, ok thanks. So if you boot in text mode does that work?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It's the same thing. It shows the text "username login:" and then shows the black screen with the blinking cursor

You may need to switch out of the (broken) graphical mode back to the text console. That's what I'm asking you to do.

@ChrisDavies, thanks, I would really appreciate it if explain the steps that I need to take please

You should know how to do that, as if you're using Kali you'll presumably be an experienced Linux user. Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2 or F3 (I don't know which will be appropriate for Kali; just try them)

Thank you. I know what text mode is, but I did not know how to switch to it since I had never had such an issue that required it. Anyway, I am in text mode using Ctrl+Alt+F2. should I remount the file system as indicated in the solution?

It did not help!

In what way did it not help? Please be precise - remember we're not with you

"In what way did it not help?" I'm confused. I have tried the top-voted solution in the question posted in Ask Ubuntu which I have added a link to in my post. remember read the post
